# cant find my address from MEW when i want to connect my ledger nano s

Tags: ledger-nano-s

cant find my address from MEW when i want to connect my ledger nano s, I see a lot of addresses but not mine and all of the adresses have 0 ETH

Comment: Can you please add some more information on how you are connecting and may be provide a screenshot, this might help to understand your problem better.

Comment: I connected my ledger nano S to my laptop and selected the ethereum app (browser on), then i went to MEW to log in to my account. I tried to open my address with the option Ledger and selected  m/44'/60'/0'
Ledger (ETH). Below I tried to find my 'MEW' address but i can't find my adress.

Comment: I have the same issue, I can't find my adress anymore in the list....
Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hello. If you have a new question please use [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). If you are interested in this question please hit the favorite button near the question post.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18193)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself after all.
You won't see your old MEW in ledger nano s.
You will have to use one of the ledger nano s addresses and transfer your funds from your old MEW address to the address provided by ledger.

Hope this helped you.